# Can’t install 18.04 from live usb. Screen freezes, but cursor moves

Tags: 18.04, kernel, screen, cursor, inspiron

I’m trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, but when I get past gnu grub. The mouse may or may not move and be able to click on items on the screen for a maximum of five seconds, but after five seconds it continues to move, just without being able to click on anything. The keyboard is also comepletely unresponsive at this point, so I can’t even use Ctrl+alt+delete to send me back to grub or something. The errors (such as acpi, hardware, and lspcon) are in the picture below.

Kernel error messages right after grub, and before install window load up:
- [    0.000000] ACPI error: 1 table load failures, 10 successful (20170831/tbxf load-246)
- 12 Hardware errors
- Failed to probe lspcon
- LSPCON init failed on port B

Laptop:
- Dell Inspiron 15 7567 gaming laptop
- CPU: Intel core i5 7300HQ @2.5GHz
- RAM: 8gb
- GPU: 4gb NVIDIA 1050Ti
- storage: 256gb ssd, 2tb hdd

Things I know for sure:
- Already has latest bios
- Made live usb with Rufus
- The dick check from grub said no files had errors

Answer (score 0):

Please try edit kernel parameters in grub menu by change `quite splash` to `nomodeset` to gain access to desktop environment.
After that update your graphic card driver, and choosing NVIDIA proprietary instead of `xorg` in `Additional driver`